# Help need to write mathematical equation

Tags: multiple-regression, model

I have created hedonic model. I understand what I am doing, but to present in a paper I need to write mathematically. Can one please help? Many thanks

Log(Capital_value_psf) = Micro_Post_code + Year + Area_Post_code + Area_Post_code x year + Sector_type

Micro_Post_Code goes down to four digits, therefore focused on a narrow area. WHereas, Area_Post_code looks at district level (wider area).

Comment: I've answered this question here, but keep in mind that I may have been for suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about what you're exactly looking for, but is the following OK?:

$$\log{V} = C_m + Y + C_a + C_a \cdot y + S$$

Where $V$ stands for Capital_value_psf, C_m represents Micro_Post_code and so on. State very clearly what every symbol means before using them... Some authors use longer abbreviations of the words in their equations, but I think that's a bit unpleasant to look at. Compare to:

$$\log(CVpsf) = CPM + Year + CPA + CPA \cdot year + ST$$

This looks a bit more unclear, as two consecutive letters in an name may be confused with a multiplication

Comment: Sorry I meant was in greeks

Comment: Do you mean greek letters? OK, use greek letters if you wish